# using .htaccess to play video again after ended

Tags: .htaccess, using

i want to use .htaccess to play video again after ended

my device support only direct video url like that

```
http://host/video.mp4
```

it works but when ended it stop and not play again

Comment: I don't understand how htaccess could help here. What would you want to do ?

Comment: video link as this http://host/video.mp4 , i use vlc to play it and it play until end then stop , I want to play it again when ended.

Comment: I already understood that part. What i don't understand is why you think htaccess can be a solution for your problem